# When an arbitrary point belongs to a given pyramid?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Suppose that we fix points $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}^3$ which do not belong to the same plane.

How can we check algebraically whether $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ to their convex hull?

Comment: I suppose one option is to use an affine transformation $T$ to map $a, b, c, d$ respectively to $(0, 0, 0, 0)$, $(0, 1, 0, 0)$, $(0, 0, 1, 0)$, $(0, 0, 0, 1)$. Then, $x$ is in the convex hull iff $Tx$ is in the transformed pyramid, that is, if all of the coordinates of $Tx$ are nonnegative and the sum of its coordinates is $\leq 1$.

Comment: Im sorry Dietrich, I wasn't able to find that question. Close it if necessary.. (and thanks for the comment!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to compute the plane containing $a,b,c$ and check that $x$ and $d$ are on the same side.  Repeat this with all other sets of three points from $a,b,c,d$.  If $x$ is always on the same side of the plane as the odd point out, it is in the convex hull.